# Testes na Linguagem JavaScript Behavior Driven Design (Desenvolvimento Guiado por Comportamento)

Tags: javascript, testes-de-unidade

Em linguagens como PHP e Java, por exemplo, os testes seguem mais o conceito do teste de unidade. No mundo JavaScript dizem que a abordagem é um pouco diferente e está sendo difundida a terminologia *Behavior Driven Design* (BDD).

Desconsiderando as diferenças entre as linguagens citadas, Neste [link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) diz que BDD tem uma diferença conceitual:

- **BDD é uma técnica de desenvolvimento Ágil que encoraja colaboração entre desenvolvedores, setores de qualidade e pessoas não-técnicas ou de negócios num projeto de software, se relaciona com o conceito de verificação e validação.**

Sinceramente a frase "**é uma técnica de desenvolvimento Ágil que encoraja colaboração entre desenvolvedores**" me confundiu.

Junit e PHPunit não compartilham deste mesmo conceito? Não consegui entender a diferença que os testes em JavaScript podem ser diferentes dos testes aplicados em JUnit ou PHPUnit.

Comment: Ainda bem que confundiu porque tudo o que está escrito aí é *bull shit*. Tem muita gente *$%#@! um monte re regra que nem entende e espera que os outros entendam e façam o que eles mandaram. Em geral é conteúdo de segunda mão pra gerar conteúdo à qualquer preço. Qualquer pessoa que tenha um pouco de experiência (real) lê a frase e liga o alerta na hora porque la não quer dizer nada. As pessoas que criam essas coisas nunca provaram que dá um resultado bom.

Comment: Sempre importante notar que o fato de alguém ter formalizado um conceito não tem relação nenhuma com ele ser bom ou não. Nas últimas décadas infelizmente o que mais tem em TI é gente desqualificada tentando compensar com publicação de documentos aleatórios para não morrer no esquecimento.